# asp JQuery Setting Runtime Variables - undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I'm struggling to get this code to work. Basically I need to verify that the user is logged in before running the code block below:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  const loggedIn = '<%#(UIContext.Current != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UIContext.Current.AuthTokens.IdToken))%>'.toLowerCase() === "true";

  if (!loggedIn) {
      $("#breadcrumbTableContainer").css("display", "none");
      $("#priNavContainer").css("display", "none");
      $("#priNavContainerWrap").css("display", "none");
      $(".headerContainer.stepsHeaderCont").css("display", "none");
  } else {
      // UserPilot
      var uiContext = '<%# UIContext.Current %>';

      if (uiContext != null) {
          console.log('UTCDateTime: <%# DateTime.UtcNow%>');
          console.log('Association:  <%# UIContext.Current.CurrentAssociation.Name %>');
          console.log('Association ID: <%# UIContext.Current.CurrentAssociation.ID %>');
          console.log('User Name: <%#UserName%>');
          console.log('User ID: <%# UIContext.Current.CurrentUser.ID%>');
          console.log('URL: ' + window.location);

          // End UserPilot
      }
...
```

I understand that I'm using serverside variables and that is what is causing the problem as UIContext.Current is null. What is the proper way to approach this?

In addition if I modify the code to:

```
console.log('Association: ' + uiContext.CurrentAssociation.Name);
```

uiContext is undefined.

Comment: Is this WebForms? And what is `UIContext`?

Comment: `var uiContext = '<%# UIContext.Current %>';`  will NEVER result in `uiContext.CurrentAssociation.Name` being available to JavaScript on the client. IF `UIContext.Current` contains a JSON string, then you can do `var uiContext = <%# UIContext.Current %>;` WITHOUT the quotes and then you might find a CurrentAssociation.Name in there

Comment: Its a legacy product using classic asp. UIContext is a custom class that holds many properties about the User and the session info.

Comment: It isn't JSON... I tried without the quotes and it comes back with:  (Clientside code) var uiContext = MemberSuite.UI.Views.UIContext;

Comment: What client-side code does this server-side code produce?  How does it differ from what you expect?  *"what is causing the problem as UIContext.Current is null"* - Why specifically do you expect it not to be `null`?  If the problem is that this property is `null` then it sounds like the problem is **before** the code shown.  You'll likely want to do some additional debugging to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Based on The responses, I did some more digging. The issue is that since this is the master page when a user hits the login screen UIContext is null until they successfully login. But since the server side code is retrieved before the page is shown I'm getting exceptions because the UIContext hasn't been instantiated yet.

Comment: Is it possible to do a inline server-side code block for this? I don't know how but it seems like that is the only way to get this to work?

Comment: @RSH It's not Classic ASP, this is definitely some form of ASP.Net as `DateTime.UtcNow` is a .Net class property. Also, `<%#` is not valid Classic ASP syntax. This looks like ASP.Net WebForms to me (which some may consider "Classic").

Comment: @RSH: What do you mean by "inline server-side code block"?  Where does `UIContext` come from?  If it's not populated before the page is returned to the user then when *is* it populated?  It's not clear to me what you're trying to describe.  (Also, in reference to a "master page"... You'd previously indicated that this is "classic ASP", but other indications suggest that this is ASP.NET Web Forms.  Can you clarify?  If you're mis-identifying the technologies you're using then that would certainly hinder your research efforts.)

Comment: You want to use "=" and not "#". Using a server side expression with "#" is ONLY for data bound controls and their markup. If you looking for "in genreal" use of a server side expression, you use <%=Some Server side expression%> and are not to use <%#%>

Comment: Not really sure why this question closed. The use of in-line server expresisons is a long time staple of asp.net applications. The simple answer is the syntax is wrong, and the "=" should be used in place of the "#" which is used for data aware and data binding of controls. So, the simple answer is the provided sample markup is incorrect by having used the "#" for the server side "in line" expressions here.

Comment: Okay the answer turned out to be quite simple using an inline if:

  console.log('PartitionKey: <%# (UIContext.Current != null ? UIContext.Current.CurrentAssociation.PartitionKey.ToString(): "n/a") %>');